# Issues with Selenium ChromeDriver when running on Remote Desktop that has low resolution

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently running my selenium testing on a server that has a low screen resolution. This causes issues while testing, especially clicking on buttons, opening dropdowns, and in general finding elements.

What can I do to overcome this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the page zoom level?

Comment: Is this happening only in case of chromeDriver & not happening with Geckodriver(firefox browser) ?

Comment: I've only tried on ChromeDriver.